# excel vba can't find open workbook

Tags: excel, vba

```
dim wb as WorkBook
set wb = ("book1.xlsm")
Application.Run "'book1.xlsm'!run"
```

the third line gives a "subscript out of range" error. book1 is open and the run function exists in it. I am completely at a loss here.

Comment: rename your `Sub` from `run` to something that does not conflict with the `Run` procedure of the `Application`. Don't use reserved words for naming your procedures. This `set wb = ("book1.xlsm")` should already fail. If your workbook is already open then use `set wb = Application.Workbooks("book1.xlsm")`. • Where exactly in the `book1.xlsm` do you have your procedure `run` it needs to be in a module (not in `ThisWorkbook` not in a table to run it that way.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ nvm I closed everything and opened it again and it worked